# Multiply input values into span

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/19gwk4q6/

Html:

```
<ul>
  <li id="1">
    <input type="text" name="1" class="parent" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rank" value="8" class="rank" />
    <span class="result"></span>
  </li>
  <li id="2">
    <input type="text" name="2" class="parent" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rank" value="1.75" class="rank" />
    <span class="result"></span>
  </li>
  <li id="3">
    <input type="text" name="1" class="parent" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rank" value="10" class="rank" />
    <span class="result"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("change", ".parent", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".parent").each(function() {
    var rank = $("input").next(".rank").val();
    sum = $(this).val() * rank;
  });
  $("input").next(".result").val(sum);
});
```

I have server side generated list and I need to multiply input values `.parent * .rank` and get result into span.result in each `<li>`. I was trying to use `.closest ()` and `.next()` functions, but it is not working.

Thank you for help!

Comment: in tag span you must use function text set value for it. $("input").next(".result").val(sum);  ---> $("input").next(".result").text(sum);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the OP it is understand that `.result` is a `span` so `$("input").next(".result").val(sum);` won't work because `span` does not have a function called `.val()` use `.text()` instead. And also change

```
 var rank = $("input").next(".rank").val();
```

to

```
var rank = $(this).next(".rank").val();
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/e8goyxa7/)

**EDIT**

Based on OP's comment. try this

```
$(document).on("change", ".parent", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".parent").each(function() {
        var rank = $(this).next(".rank").val();
        sum = $(this).val() * rank;
        $(this).parent().find(".result").text(sum);
    });

});
```

[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e8goyxa7/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It still not working correctly. When I set some value into one input, it returns 0 into all result spans.

Comment: what is your expecting output?

Comment: Example: When I set 10 to <input name="1" class="parent"> it will be multiplied by value <input name="rank" value="8">, it means it returns 80 to <span class="result"> in <li id="1">

Answer (score 0):

Have you try

```
var rank = $(this).siblings(".rank").val();

$(this).siblings(".result").val(sum);
```